# Hibernate method giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have created a method `addRolesToUser()` and this method has 2 parameters, a `Role` object and a `User` object.

```
public class UserImp implements UserInterfaceDao{
private Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     @Override
    public void addRolesToUser(Role roles,UserDao user){

      try{
              session.beginTransaction();
              user.getRoles().add(roles);
              session.save(user);
              session.save(roles);
              session.getTransaction().commit();
                }

         }catch(HibernateException e){
             session.getTransaction().rollback();
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

but when I call this method in my `main()` method I a NullPointerException is thrown.

This is my `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        UserImp test=new UserImp();
        UserDao user=new UserDao();
        user.setNameUser("jack");


       Role roles=new Role();
       role.setNameRole("admin_role");
       test.addRolesToUser(roles, user);


the  Role Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "Role")
public class Role {
     @Id
@GenericGenerator(name="kaugen" , strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="kaugen")
    private Long idRole;
    private String nameRole;
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @ElementCollection
   private List<UserDao> users;


    public List<UserDao> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<UserDao> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getNameRole() {
        return nameRole;
    }

    public void setNameRole(String nameRole) {
        this.nameRole = nameRole;
    }

}
```

The `UserDao` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserDao")
public class UserDao implements Serializable {
     @Id
     @GenericGenerator(name="kaugen" , strategy="increment")
     @GeneratedValue(generator="kaugen")
    private Long idUser;
     @Column(name="nameUser")
    private String nameUser;
    private String emailUser;
    private String passwordUser;
     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinTable(name = "Role_User")
    private List<Role> roles;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Blog> blogs=new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Blog> getBlogs() {
        return blogs;
    }
    public void setBlogs(List<Blog> blogs) {
        this.blogs = blogs;
    }
    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getNameUser() {
        return nameUser;
    }

    public void setNameUser(String nameUser) {
        this.nameUser = nameUser;
    }

    public String getEmailUser() {
        return emailUser;
    }

    public void setEmailUser(String emailUser) {
        this.emailUser = emailUser;
    }

    public String getPasswordUser() {
        return passwordUser;
    }

    public void setPasswordUser(String passwordUser) {
        this.passwordUser = passwordUser;
    }



}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at blog.com.dao.UserImp.addRolesToUser(UserImp.java:154)
    at blog.com.dao.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Comment: which is the line 154?

Comment: Can you show the part where you initialize `session`? I suspect that is null.

Comment: i have that in HibernateUtil class     public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `user.getRoles().add(roles)` breaks because you didn't initialize user's roles. So, in `User` entity you should have something like this

```
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

Comment: i have that in my userDao : private List<Role> roles; and with getter and setter

Comment: Yes, but you didn't initialize it, note the `new ArrayList<Role>()` at the end.

Comment: Ok then, it says that the exception is in `UserImp.java:154`. What code is in that line?

Comment: in UserImp.java:154 session.beginTransaction();

Comment: So, `session` is null. Update the question with code that you use to initialize it.

Comment: session is not NULL I have create i private field and that take the session

Comment: private Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

Comment: I Update the question with code that i use to initialize the session

Comment: Nobody cant help me or what :(

Comment: `session` is null. That means `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()` returns null, and that's probably some problem with configuration. Instead of managing the session manually, take a look at [Spring transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained).

Comment: But when i do i method named addUser(UserDao user) that need to add a user into database that work perfect also i think the problem is not that session is null ..

Comment: Well, you said that line 154 is `session.beginTransaction()`. In that line, the only thing that can cause `NullPointerException` is a null session. To eliminate this, add a breakpoint to that line and check. This should be a simple issue, something in your code is null, just find it.

Comment: now the log4j said that the problem is in line 157 is is that methode session.save(user);

Comment: can that the object user and role be Null public void addRolesToUser(Role roles,UserDao user){

      try{
              session.beginTransaction();
              user.getRoles().add(roles);
              session.save(user);
              session.save(roles);
              session.getTransaction().commit();
                }

         }catch(HibernateException e){
             session.getTransaction().rollback();
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

Comment: Put a breakpoint to the beginning of the method and debug it, no point in guessing like this if you can find it out in one second. Also, are you calling that `addUser` (that works) also from main method?

Comment: yes addUser that work perfect in main method that mean the session is not null

Comment: There is still `private List<Role> roles;` in updated code, are you sure you added `private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>()`? If yes, update the code in the question.

Comment: i have initialize  a object userDao and a object Role Into addRolesToUser and that work without problem but the probelm now is when i see in the database i cant find the object UserDao and Role the column have null

Comment: Best is to ask a new question for the new problem.

Comment: OK  Predrag Maric Thankyou a lot for that :)

Answer (score 0):

now i changed the method addRolesToUser():
the code of the new one is :

```
public void addRolesToUser(Role roles,UserDao user) {

     try{ 
       session.beginTransaction();
          roles=new Role();
          user=new UserDao();
          user.getRoles().add(roles);
          session.save(roles);
          session.save(user);
          session.getTransaction().commit();



     }catch(HibernateException e){
         session.getTransaction().rollback();
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
```

when i use that method in main()the problem of nullpointerexception is resolved
but in my database the object userDao and Role they are Null notthing inside the database just null.